# Why particular characters are hard coded to generate a secured token

Tags: devise

I am just trying to understand the philosophy behind harcoding the particular characters in generating the friendly token. What is the thought process behind this

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L481

```
def self.friendly_token(length = 20)
    # To calculate real characters, we must perform this operation.
    # See SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    rlength = (length * 3) / 4
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(rlength).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')
  end
```

Here in the above snippet, l,I,O,0 are getting replaced with s, x, y, z respectively. What about the other characters that are getting generated!

Example

```
 SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(15)
 => "4-6RGWUH1SIsFlXa3C73"
```

What about R, G, W etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason behind that is to remove any characters that are confusing. (hard to distinguish)

Like an `O` can be confused with `0`

Like an `l` can be confused with `I`

Specific commit that introduces this explains it in the commit message

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/6d65c28f1f709722dd86da49241f118813ea7090